# Optimizing python function for Numba

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, optimization, numba

The following is the python function which I am trying to rewrite in python:

```python
def freeoh_count_nojit(coord=np.array([[]]),\
    molInterfaceIndex=np.array([]),\
    hNeighbourList=np.array([]),\
    topol=np.array([[]]),\
    cos_HAngle=0.0,\
    cellsize=np.array([]),\
    is_orig_def=False,is_new_def=True):
    labelArray=[]
    freeOHcosDA=[]; freeOHcosDAA=[]
    mol1Coord=np.zeros((3,3),dtype=float)
    labelArray=np.empty(molInterfaceIndex.shape[0], dtype="U10")
     
    for i in range(molInterfaceIndex.shape[0]):                                       # loop over selected molecules
        mol2CoordList=[]; timesave=[]
        mol1Coord=np.array([coord[k] for k in topol[molInterfaceIndex[i]]])           # extract center molecule
        gen = np.array([index for index in hNeighbourList[i] if index!=-1])           # remove padding
        for j in range(gen.shape[0]):                                                 
            mol2CoordList.append([coord[k] for k in topol[gen[j]]])         # extract neighbors
        mol2Coord=np.array(mol2CoordList).reshape(-1,3)
        if is_orig_def:
           acceptor,donor,cosAngle=interface_hbonding_orig(mol1Coord,mol2Coord,cos_HAngle,cellsize)
           labelArray[i]="D"*np.abs(2-np.sum(donor))+"A"*np.clip(np.array([np.sum(acceptor)]),1,2)[0]
        elif is_new_def:
           acceptor,donor,cosAngle=interface_hbonding_new(mol1Coord,mol2Coord,cos_HAngle,cellsize)          
           labelArray[i]="D"*np.abs(2-np.sum(donor))+"A"*np.sum(acceptor)
        if labelArray[i] in "DA":
           freeOHcosDA.append(cosAngle)
        elif labelArray[i] in "DAA":
           freeOHcosDAA.append(cosAngle)

    freeOHcos=freeOHcosDA+freeOHcosDAA
           
    return labelArray, freeOHcos
```

The function takes in a coordinates frame of the simulation molecules. The code selects a central molecule from an index list `molInterfaceIndex` and extracts its neighbouring molecules coordinates from a pre-generated neighbour (generated from  `scipy.spatial.KDTree` hence cannot be called from a jitted function). The central molecule and its neighbour are send to a jitted function which then returns two [1,1] and a scaler which are then used to label the central molecule.

My attempt at rewriting the above python function is below:

```python
@njit(cache=True,parallel=True)
def freeoh_count_jit(coord=np.array([[]]),\
    molInterfaceIndex=np.array([]),\
    hNeighbourList=np.array([]),\
    topol=np.array([[]]),\
    cos_HAngle=0.0,\
    cellsize=np.array([]),\
    is_orig_def=False,is_new_def=True):

    NAtomsMol=3                                                                     #No. of atoms in a molecule
    _M=molInterfaceIndex.shape[0]
    _N=hNeighbourList.shape[1]
    mol1Coord=np.zeros((NAtomsMol,3),dtype=np.float64)
    mol2Coord=np.zeros((_N*NAtomsMol,3),dtype=np.float64)
    acceptor=np.zeros((_M,2),dtype=int)
    donor=np.zeros((_M,2),dtype=int)
    cosAngle=np.zeros(_M,dtype=np.float64)
    gen=np.zeros(_M,dtype=int)
    freeOHMask = np.zeros(_M, dtype=int) == 0

    labelArray=np.empty(_M, dtype="U10")
    for i in range(_M):                                       # loop over selected molecules
        for index,j in enumerate(topol[molInterfaceIndex[i]]):
            mol1Coord[index]=coord[j]                                               # extract center molecule
        for indexJ,j in enumerate(hNeighbourList[i]):
            for indexK,k in enumerate(topol[j]):
                mol2Coord[indexK+topol[j].shape[0]*indexJ]=coord[k]                       # extract neighbors
        gen[i] = len(np.array([index for index in hNeighbourList[i] if index!=-1]))*NAtomsMol # get actual number of neighbor atoms
        if is_orig_def:
           acceptor[i],donor[i],cosAngle[i]=interface_hbonding_orig(mol1Coord,mol2Coord[:gen[i]],cos_HAngle,cellsize)
           labelArray[i]="D"*np.abs(2-np.sum(donor[i]))+"A"*np.clip(np.array([np.sum(acceptor[i])]),1,2)[0]
        elif is_new_def:
           acceptor[i],donor[i],cosAngle[i]=interface_hbonding_new(mol1Coord,mol2Coord[:gen[i]],cos_HAngle,cellsize)
           labelArray[i]="D"*np.abs(2-np.sum(donor[i]))+"A"*np.sum(acceptor[i])
        
   
    freeOHMask[np.where(cosAngle > 1.0)] = False

    return acceptor, donor, labelArray, freeOHMask
```

The main issue is that `@jit` function seem to be providing incorrect results while using `numba.prange` for the outer loop. Also, the execution time for the function increases per call which is a bit confusing. The functions  `interface_hbonding_orig()` and `interface_hbonding_new()` are already jitted so I think they are out of scope of discussion here. One of the bigger questions is that **whether I even to jit this function at all** as the most time consuming part is supposing to be the array selection in the initial few initial lines in the outer loop. If anyone has any suggestions for rewriting this function or even for algorithm design, it would be really helpful.

Comment: First run of the "numba-optimized" function will be slower due to compilation. You can speed-up compilation using signatures (e.g. `@jit("float32[:](int32[:], float64[:])"`). Parallelization is not working because you *probably* have non-independent computations in each process - make sanity check - invert iteration order (`for i in reversed(range(_M))`. If your code is parallizable, you should get same results as with standard order.

Comment: @dankal444 At least in the current version (0.56.4) of numba I cannot use ```reversed``` but changing the line ```for i in range(_M)``` to ```for i in range(_M-1,-1,-1):``` I can get the same answer. I am still trying to figure out the numba signature for my function.

Comment: @dankal444 Also in its current form the code is *not* parallelized.

Comment: Ok, so it seems code is parallelizable. Tell me in "numpy language" what your inputs and outputs are, for example: `input: float64 2d array`, I'll tell you signature.

Comment: @dankal444 Input(Coord: float64 2d array, molInterfaceIndex: int 1d array,  hNeighbourList : int 2d array,  topol: int 2d array,  cos_HAngle: float, cellsize:  float64 1d array,  is_orig_def:  bool, is_new_def=bool) -> Output( acceptor:  int 2d array,  donor: int 2d array, labelArray: U10 1d array , freeOHMask: float64 1d array)

Comment: First `from numba import types`, then `@nb.jit('UniTuple(int64[:, :], int64[:, :], types.unicode_type, float64[:])(float64[:, :], int64[:], int64[:, :], int64[:, :], float64, float64[:], boolean, boolean)`. Sorry if I made some mistake , this is quite a signature to deal with. I do not understand though, your code does not reflect this signature at all

Comment: @dankal444 This is the output of ```freeoh_count_jit.nopython_signatures``` ```[(array(float64, 2d, C), array(int64, 1d, C), array(int64, 2d, C), array(int64, 2d, C), float64, readonly array(float64, 1d, A), omitted(default=False), omitted(default=True)) -> Tuple(array(int64, 1d, C), array(int64, 1d, C), array([unichr x 10], 1d, C), array(float64, 1d, C))] ```

Comment: maybe instead of `boolean` it should be `bool_`, I think there is difference between python boolean and numpy boolean